# Python reads \\ when \ is the input

Tags: python, string, append

I am trying to create a new text file in an empty folder. The path to the folder is:

```
C:\Users\Tor\Desktop\Python files\retning
```

When I type this in the command line in windows explorer, I get straight to the empty folder.

When I type my code in Python I get an errormessage and it looks like Python has replaced a couple of the `'\'` with `'\\'`

This is my code

```
   sector='A5'
   g=open('C:\Users\Tor\Desktop\Python files\retning\retning'+sector+'.txt', 'a')
```

and this is the errormessage

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tor\Desktop\Python files\filer som behandler output\Vindretning.py", line 2, in <module>
    g=open('C:\Users\Tor\Desktop\Python files\retning\retning'+sector+'.txt', 'a')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('a') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Tor\\Desktop\\Python files\retning\retningA5.txt'
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong, or what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` needs to be escaped in the strings. That is why `\\` or raw strings are used (`r'test String'`)

Using raw strings solves the problem here. Something like,

```
open(r'C:\Programming Test Folder\test_file.py')
```

So, your code gets changed to

```
g=open(r'C:\Users\Tor\Desktop\Python files\retning\retning{}.txt'.format(sector), 'a')
```

Or use `/` in Windows, like follows

```
g=open('C:/Users/Tor/Desktop/Python files/retning/retning'+sector+'.txt', 'a')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is *normal* behaviour; Python is giving you a string representation that can be pasted right back into a Python script or interpreter prompt. Since `\` is a character used in Python string literals to start an escape sequence (such as `\n` or `\xa0`) the backslashes are doubled.

In fact, it is the characters *without* escaped backslashes that are the key here; `\r` is the escape code for a carriage return. You need to use one of the following options to specify Windows paths instead:

- Escape all backslashes by doubling them in your string literals:

  ```
  g = open('C:\\Users\\Tor\\Desktop\\Python files\\retning\\retning'+sector+'.txt', 'a')
  ```

  Now the `\r` won't be interpreted as an escape code.
- Use a raw string literal:

  ```
  g = open(r'C:\Users\Tor\Desktop\Python files\retning\retning'+sector+'.txt', 'a')
  ```

  In raw string literals most escape codes are ignored.
- Use *forward* slashes:

  ```
  g = open('C:/Users/Tor/Desktop/Python files/retning/retning'+sector+'.txt', 'a')
  ```

  Forward slashes work fine as path separators on Windows, and there's no chance of them being interpreted as escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

In a normal python string, a backslash can have a special meaning (for instance, `\n` indicates a new line). In the path you've provided in your code, you either need to use `\\` for each directory separator (`\\` means include a ), or mark the string as a raw string, meaning the special treatment for backslashes doesn't apply. You do that with an r before the quote mark, like `r'Folder\Sub-Folder\Another'`

The error message is basically python giving you the python code you can use to get your original string.